# Discord.js Commando Broadcast All command error

Tags: discord.js, commando

I'm trying to make broadcast command send a message to all text channels in the guild. My current code looks like this:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class broadcastCommand extends Commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'broadcast',
      aliases: ['bcast', 'bc'],
      group: 'ebs',
      memberName: 'broadcast',
      userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
      description: 'Sends an emergency broadcast to the emergency brodcast channel',
      examples: ['bc ALERT! SUSPICIOUS ENTITY SPOTTED IN DELTA QUADRANT SECTOR B-3! ALL PERSONEL PROCEED WITH CAUTION!'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'text',
          prompt: 'What would you like to broadcast?',
          type: 'string',
        },
      ],
    })
  };

  run(msg, { text }) {

    let channel = msg.guild.channels.forEarch(channel => {
      if (channel.type === 'text') channel.send(`${text}`); {
        tts: true
      };
    })
  }
};
```

My issue is that it gives me a error on using it. This is the error:

```
11|EBS     |     at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:314:20)
11|EBS     |     at GuildMemberRemoveAction.handle (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/GuildMemberRemove.js:20:62)
11|EBS     |     at GuildMemberRemoveHandler.handle (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildMemberRemove.js:9:38)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
11|EBS     |     at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
11|EBS     | /home/nimbi/ebs/EBS.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
11|EBS     | (node:28491) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
11|EBS     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
11|EBS     | /home/nimbi/ebs/EBS.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
11|EBS     | (node:22022) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
11|EBS     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this. It's needed for a SciFi LARP server that I'm helping a friend build.

I'm on Node 12.x and using Discord.JS Commando

I've also tried this:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class broadcastCommand extends Commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'broadcast',
      aliases: ['ebcast', 'bcast', 'bc', 'ebc'],
      group: 'ebs',
      memberName: 'broadcast',
      userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
      description: 'Sends an emergency broadcast to the emergency brodcast channel',
      examples: ['bc ALERT! SUSPICIOUS ENTITY SPOTTED IN DELTA QUADRANT SECTOR B-3! ALL PERSONEL PROCEED WITH CAUTION!'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'text',
          prompt: 'What would you like to broadcast?',
          type: 'string',
        },
      ],
    })
  };

  run(msg, { text }) {

    const channels = msg.guild.channels.filter(c => c.guild && c.type === 'text');
    Promise.all(channels.map(c => c.send(`${text}`))); {
      tts: true
    };
  }
};
```

However it gave this error:

```
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
11|EBS     |     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
11|EBS     |     at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/nimbi/ebs/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
11|EBS     | /home/nimbi/ebs/EBS.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
11|EBS     | (node:28491) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
11|EBS     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
11|EBS     | /home/nimbi/ebs/EBS.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
11|EBS     | (node:22022) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
11|EBS     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
11|EBS     | /home/nimbi/ebs/EBS.sh: line 1: !#/bin/sh: No such file or directory
11|EBS     | (node:22853) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
11|EBS     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Another thing I've tried is this:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class broadcastCommand extends Commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'broadcast',
      aliases: ['ebcast', 'bcast', 'bc', 'ebc'],
      group: 'ebs',
      memberName: 'broadcast',
      userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
      description: 'Sends an emergency broadcast to the emergency brodcast channel',
      examples: ['bc ALERT! SUSPICIOUS ENTITY SPOTTED IN DELTA QUADRANT SECTOR B-3! ALL PERSONEL PROCEED WITH CAUTION!'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'text',
          prompt: 'What would you like to broadcast?',
          type: 'string',
        },
      ],
    })
  };

  run(msg, { text }) {

    const channel_list = msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.id ===  ['759042556972630036', '759042556972630037', '759042556972630038', '759061573867405312', '759042556536553557', '759801988560322611', '759116305218666496'])

 
    return channel_list.send(`${ text }`); {
      tts: true
    };
  }
};
```

However that failed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reasonably on the right track. The biggest issue is that you define the [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) outside of the `.send` function.

Check the code example below and give it a try.

```js
run(msg, { text}) {
  // Note if you're using Discord JS version 12.0.0 or higher, you need to use '.channels.cache'
  // If you're using Discord JS version 11.1.0 or lower, remove the '.cache'
  msg.guild.channels.cache
    .filter(channel => channel.type === 'text')
    .forEach((textChannel) => {
      textChannel.send(text, {tts: true});
    });
}
```